# Aggregate Operations over Multiple Columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, multiple-columns, aggregate-functions

I have multiple columns with integer values such as D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, etc.
I would like to have the maximum value of those multiple columns by each row. When I try to write a query like below:

```
SELECT MAX(D18, D17, D16), cust_id
FROM my_db
GROUP BY cust_id
```

It returns an error:

```
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
```

How can I handle this problem? I use PostgreSQL. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try replacing `MAX` with `GREATEST`.

Comment: Or even `MAX(GREATEST(a, b, c))`, depending on what you're doing *(which you don't make particularly clear)*